# Ember App Kit + RESTAdapter + PHP - PUT request fails

Tags: php, symfony, ember.js

I'm using Ember App kit and Ember Data to communicate with server, till now everything worked great, I managed to create models and  retrieve data using RESTAdapter.

I implemented JSON API using Symfony2.

But now when I want to save edited data to server and when I call save() method on model it sends OPTIONS request to server but XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myservice.ge/customers/1. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

I know that you can not send PUT requests from browser to other domain and I'm not asking how to do it.

My question is how can I use Ember App Kit and it's features and have service and front app on same domain? when I start Ember App Kit using grunt, it starts on port 8000 and my apache which serves PHP is running on port 80.

I could jus copy + paste Ember App Kit's generated result to same domain as apache using grunt but I wander if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not best way to do this but it worked for me.

This solution is for symfony2 but same logic will work anywhere.

I just added this to app_dev.php(or anywhere your app's entry point is):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type ');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type ');
```

Now if you are using  Symfony2 you have to add "methods" parameter to your routes in routing.yml file:

Example of router in routing.yml :

```
user_update:
    pattern:  /users/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:User:update }
    methods: [PUT, OPTIONS]
```